# CentOS 7, 2 NIC ports, 2 subnets configured, but both not working simultaneously

Tags: networking, centos

I have set up a CentOS 7.6 server (Lenovo SR650 with x722 10 GbE card) and have tried to designate the two NIC ports (not 2 NICs, just 2 ports) to be on different subnets with different gateways etc. I have statically configured each interface (eno1, and eno2) to have separate IPs and Gateways, and added route-enoX and rule-enoX for both interfaces. And yet when I bring up the second port (eno2), I lose connection to eno1.  I can SSH into the eno2 IP (different subnet), but can't SSH to eno1.  If I bring eno2 down, I can then access eno1 again.

Although I do have some experience in network administration, I am not familiar with this problem.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

The configs below are for eno1, and eno2 is similar.

IFCFG-ENO1

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
NAME=eno1
UUID=c82f3e2f-466b-4afb-95dd-492720551d2c
DEVICE=eno1
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.9.9
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.9.1
DNS1=10.1.1.198
DNS2=10.1.1.189
ZONE=public
```

ROUTE-ENO1

```
default via 192.168.9.1 dev eno1 table 1
192.168.9.0/24 dev eno1 src 192.168.9.9 table 1
```

RULE-ENO1

```
from 192.168.9.9/32 table 1
```

IP ROUTE (includes eno2)

```
default via 192.168.9.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 100
default via 10.10.0.1 dev eno2 proto static metric 101
10.10.0.0/23 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.0.80 metric 101
192.168.9.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.9.9 metric 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue you should setup the policy based routing to answer through the `eno2` interface, like you've done for the `eno1` interface.

In your current configuration the answers from address `10.10.0.80` will be routed through the `eno1` interface anyway.

To sure in that you can use commands:

- `ip route get 8.8.8.8 from 10.10.0.80`
- `tcpdump -ni eno1 'ip host 10.10.0.80'`

```
# setup the separate routing table to answer through eno1 interface
ip route add 192.168.9.0/24 dev eno1 table 1
ip route add 0/0 via 192.168.9.1 dev eno1 table 1

# set the separate routing table to answer through eno2 interface
ip route add 10.10.0.0/23 dev eno2 table 2
ip route add 0/0 via 10.10.0.1 dev eno2 table 2

# route packets with source address 192.168.9.9 through table 1
ip rule add from 192.168.9.9 table 1 pref 10001

# route packets with source address 10.10.0.80 through table 2
ip rule add from 10.10.0.80 table 2 pref 10002
```

Also you should switch the `rp_filter` to the loose mode, otherwise the incoming packets from non-directly-connected addresses can be dropped.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eno1.rp_filter=2
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eno2.rp_filter=2
```

Comment: Thank you, Anton.  How do I make sure those ip routes are permanent?

Comment: Write the routes and the rules into the configuration files. The ip tool doesn't make the permanent changes - after reboot they will be lost.

Comment: I've tried to find which config files to put them in, but I can't find exactly what needs to be done, as there's a lot of advice online.  Can you clarify how they get written in and to which files?

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-<iface>` and `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-<iface>`

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't seem to be bringing up rule-eno1, here are the contents:
`from 192.168.9.9 table 1 pref 10001`

If I do it manually with ip add rule, it works...

Comment: In order to get this working across restarts, I had to follow this tutorial, it's in Japanese so use Google Translate: http://blog.serverworks.co.jp/tech/2018/02/16/rhel-pbr-setting/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need:

ROUTE-ENO2

```
default via 10.10.0.1 dev eno2 table 2
10.10.0.0/23 dev eno2 src 10.10.0.80 table 1
```

RULE-ENO2

```
from 10.10.0.80/32 table 2
```

or something along the lines.

What is likely happening when you bring up eno2 is that traffic related to 10.10.0.80 which needs to go through the gateway is routed via 192.168.9.1 as this entry precedes 10.10.0.1 and is probably dropped there.